# Can't get Nose to honor the attributes I set on my tests

Tags: python, django, testing, nose, django-nose

I'm using Django 1.7 with django-nose 1.4 and nose 1.3.6.

According to the [documentation](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html), I should be able to select tests to be run by using attributes. I have a test set like this:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr
from django_webtest import TransactionWebTest

@attr(isolation="menu")
class MenuTestCase(TransactionWebTest):

    def test_home(self):
        pass
```

When I try to run my tests with:

```
./manage.py test -a isolation
```

Nose eliminates all tests from the run. In other words, it does not run *any* test. Note that when I do not use `-a`, all the tests run fine. I've also tried:

- `-a=isolation`
- `-a isolation=menu`
- `-a=isolation=menu`
- `-a '!isolation'`

The last one should select almost all of my test suite since the `isolation` attribute is used only on one class but it does not select anything! I'm starting to think I just don't understand how the whole attributes system works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear to me what causes the problem. It probably has to do with how Django passes the command line arguments to django-nose, which then passes them to nose. At any rate, using the long form of the command line arguments solves the problem:

```
$ ./manage.py test --attr=isolation
```

and similarly:

- `--attr=isolation=menu`
- `--attr='!isolation'` (with the single quotes to prevent the shell form interpreting `!`)
- `--eval-attr=isolation`
- `--eval-attr='isolation=="menu"'` (the single quotes prevent the shell from removing the double quotes)
- etc...